# Linear Algebra-Eigenvalues/vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a $m*n$ martrix and suppose $v$ is an eigenvector of $AA^T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda\ne0$.

a) show that $u=A^{T}v$ cannot be the zero vector.

b) show that $\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue of $A^{T}A$. (Hint: consider $u$ given in (a).)

This is what i have for part (a): $$(AA^T)v=\lambda v$$ $$A^{-1}AA^Tv=\lambda A^{-1}v$$ $$A^Tv=\lambda A^{-1}v $$

Now, $\lambda\ne0$ is given, and $A^{-1}$ and $v$ cannot be zero.

Then, $A^Tv$ is not a zero vector.

How do i prove part (b)?

Comment: What is $A^TA\mathbf{u}$?

Comment: Note that in general you cannot invert an $m*n$ matrix.

Comment: @Tpofofn how do i prove part a if i cant use $A^{-1}$ ?

Comment: Even if $A$ were square, you can’t assume that it’s nonsingular. All you know is that it has at least one nonzero eigenvalue, not that *all* of its eigenvalues are nonzero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given that $\mathbf{v}$ is an eigenvector of $AA^T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda\ne 0$.  Rephrase using the definition of what it means to be an eigenvector. $$AA^T\mathbf{v}=\lambda\mathbf{v}$$ for some $\mathbf{v}\ne\mathbf{0}$.

For part (a) ask yourself what would happen if $A^T\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}$ and why this is impossible.

For part (b) again use the definition.  If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A^TA$ then there must exist a nonzero $\mathbf{x}$ such that $$A^TA\mathbf{x}=\lambda\mathbf{x}.$$  The hint suggests what $\mathbf{x}$ you might try.

Comment: thanks for the hint for for part a. can you explain part (b) a little more?

Comment: Put $\mathbf{x}=A^T\mathbf{v}$ into the left hand side above and see what happens.

Comment: $A^TAu=A^TAA^Tv=A^T\lambda v$. wht do i do next?

Comment: So you've shown that $$A^TA(A^T\mathbf{v})=\lambda(A^T\mathbf{v})$$
which is what it means for $A^Tv$ to be an eigenvector of $A^TA$.  That's it.  You're done.  It will serve you well to think about why and make sure you understand why.